# What are the semantics of input variables passed by reference?

Tags: plc, twincat, codesys, iec61131-3

Beckhoff's TwinCat-3, as well as Codesys 3 it's based on, adds references as an extension to IEC-61131-3 languages. I'm wondering what is the exact grammar and semantics of this non-standard addition (that's the problem with them: nobody bothers documenting them as well as a standard would).

It the following `F_IsNonEmpty` function valid and doing what one would expect, when invoked from the `F_Test` test function below?

```
FUNCTION F_IsNonEmpty : BOOL
  VAR_INPUT
    text : REFERENCE TO STRING;
  END_VAR
  F_IsNonEmpty := LEN(text) > 0;
END_FUNCTION

FUNCTION F_Test1
  VAR
    testMessage : STRING := '123';
  END_VAR
  IF F_IsNonEmpty(text := testMessage) THEN
    {...}
  END_IF
END_FUNCTION
```

Given that the target of the reference must be initialized using the `REF=` operator (v.s. e.g. C++ where reference targets are immutable), I'd have expected that the following invoking code would be correct instead - but it doesn't even compile:

```
FUNCTION F_Test2
  VAR
    testMessage : STRING := '123';
  END_VAR
  IF F_IsNonEmpty(text REF= testMessage) THEN
    {...}
  END_IF
END_FUNCTION
```

It seems that `F_Test1` works correctly, but I'd like someone who actually uses Codesys 3 or TwinCat-3 `REFERENCE TO` feature to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a REFERENCE in a VAR_INPUT, it's as if you were using a VAR_IN_OUT variable.
Otherwise if you declare your REFERENCE in the VAR section, you need to use REF= when assigning another variable to it (or get an exception).

In essence, REFERENCE (like a VAR_IN_OUT var) is a more convenient and "safe" pointer because the  dereference operator ^ is not needed and because the type is checked at compile time.

Comment: There is as subtle but important difference between var_in_out and var_input. You have to write the var_in_out in every cycle. If you don't do that the variable will be null if not written first. With var_input you can write once and it keeps the value over cycles.

Comment: That's true but the compiler will generate an error if the var_in_out var is not set when you call the function block and generally you should always check references/pointers before accessing them.